# How to save signalR chat messages to database

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, signalr

I'm new to SignalR and I need to use a real-time chat in my ASP.NET MVC web application. So I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
The question is what do I need to do in order to save messages to my PostgreSQL Database so I can later show the list of all messages? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with SignalR really, if you need to save the messages in a database you need to write some method that does that saving, probably at the same moment as the message is sent. Not sure if that's what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already implemented the chat, you just need to implement the database, using a manager, inject the manager in to your hub and save/get the messages.

Since you did not provided any code, look at this example:

Inject the database manager in to your hub using DI.

```cs
private IDatabaseManager DatabaseManager
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseManager>();
    }
}
```

Then you just create two methods in your hub to be called by the client when it connects to the chat to get the messages, for example:

```cs
public async Task JoinChatRoom(string chatRoomName)
{
    await this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(chatRoomName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Dictionary<string, string> messages = await this.DatabaseManager.GetChatHistory(chatRoomName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await this.Clients.Group(chatRoomName).BroadcastMessageAsync(messages);
}
```

And save each message in the chat like:

```cs
public async Task SendMessageToRoom(string message, string chatRoomName)
{
    await this.DatabaseManager.SaveChatHistory(chatRoomName, message).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await this.Clients.Group(chatRoomName).BroadcastMessageAsync(message);
}
```

This is just a example how you can do it.